# Spring Transaction roll back both `UPDATE` and `INSERT`

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, transactions

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class OrderService {

  //Implemented with JdbcTemplate (no ORM)
  //Both Dao use the same DataSource
  private AccountDao accountDao;
  private OrderDao orderDao;

public void update(int accountId){

  //Get account and do some calculation (simplifed version here)
  Account account = accountDao.findByid(accountId)
  int newAmount = account.getAmoount * 100;

  //Update account table 
  accountDao.updateAmount(accountId, newAmount);

  //Insert new order
  Order order = ....
  orderDao.save(order);

}

}
```

In the code above, I would like to rollback both `accountDao.updateAmount` and `orderDao.save` if the updated account row is modified by another transaction.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement optimistic locking manuallay.

Add VERSION column for each table.

When You load and entity .. you need to load the current version

when you update an entity you have to add version check in where clause and get the updated row count after execution ( `int rowCount = st.executeUpdate();` )

example : `UPDATE ACCOUNT set AMOUNT = x, VERSION = VERSION+1 where ID = XX and VERSION = CURRENT_VERSION`

If the updated row count is <> 1 it means that the row has been modified by another transaction ( UPDATE or DELETE )

Comment: i solved this using `SELECT FOR UPDATE`. However, `FOR UPDATE` doesn't work for aggregate clause...

Comment: you have used pessimistic locking it works but it has some drawbacks :
Performance, Deadlock if it's not used carefully, Lock Timeout in the waiting transaction if the running transaction is slow